How can I init an editor on a textarea added dynamically in jQuery?
I have a form where I can add many textareas as I want when I click on a button. Each textarea must be a ckeditor.
I managed to init the existing textareas but I don't know how to do it for ones added dynamically because the init is done in one file and the addition is done in another file and my init method is not recognized in my second file.
Form view:
// HTML content [...]

<script type="importmap">
    {
        "imports": {
            "ckeditor5": "https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/42.0.1/ckeditor5.js",
            "ckeditor5/": "https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/42.0.1/"
        }
    }
</script>
    
<script type="module" src="init-ckeditor.js"></script>
<script src="product.js"></script>

Init is done is done in init-ckeditor.js. This file must be type="module" to allow the plugins import.
import {
    ClassicEditor,
    Alignment,AutoLink,BalloonToolbar,Bold,Essentials,FindAndReplace,
    FontColor,FontSize,Heading,Indent,IndentBlock,
    Italic,Link,List,Paragraph,PasteFromOffice,RemoveFormat,
    SelectAll,SourceEditing,SpecialCharacters,SpecialCharactersEssentials,
    SpecialCharactersLatin,SpecialCharactersText,Superscript,Table,TableCaption,
    TableCellProperties,TableColumnResize,TableProperties,
    TableToolbar,TextTransformation,Underline,Undo
} from 'ckeditor5';

const getEditorConfig = (configName) => {
    // define different config templates
    // [...]

    return config;
}

// Init the editor on the field
const initEditor = (field, config) => {
    let editorConfig = getEditorConfig(config);

    ClassicEditor.create(field, editorConfig)
        .then( editor => {
            // Disable browser native spellchecker
            editor.editing.view.change( writer => {
                writer.setAttribute('spellcheck', 'false', editor.editing.view.document.getRoot());
            });
        })
        .catch( error => {
            console.log( error );
        })
    ;
}

// Init existing textareas
$(function() {
  $('textarea.ckeditor-basic').each(function (i, field) {
    initEditor(field, 'basic');
  });

  $('textarea.ckeditor-full').each(function (i, field) {
    initEditor(field, 'full');
  });
});

Below is product.js where I have my method to add new textareas :
const addNewField = () => {
    // create the textarea [...]
    
    // init ckeditor --> error: initEditor is not defined
    initEditor(myNewField, 'basic');

    // display field
    $('#mydiv').append(myNewField);
});

$(function() {
    $('#add-button').click(function (e) { 
        addNewField();
    });
});

Problem: when I click on the button, I have an error initEditor is not defined.
Still, init-ckeditor.js is well added before product.js.
I noticed that if I remove the type="module" in the <script> tag, the method is recognized BUT I have an error on the plugins import SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module.
It is very important that I have 2 separated files because I want to reuse all the ckeditor initiation for other pages. I am not a JS expert so I don't know how I can do...

Solution found thanks to this question: for calling initEditor() method outside the JS module, I need to export the method, then import it in an object that will be used by product.js
Form view :
// HTML content [...]

<script type="importmap">
    {
        "imports": {
            "ckeditor5": "https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/42.0.1/ckeditor5.js",
            "ckeditor5/": "https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/42.0.1/"
        }
    }
</script>

<script src="product.js"></script>    

<script type="module">
    import { initEditor } from "init-ckeditor.js";
    ckmodule.initEditor = initEditor;
</script>

In init-ckeditor.js replace this :
const initEditor = (field, config) => {

By this
export function initEditor(field, config) {

product.js :
const ckmodule = {};

const addNewField = () => {
    // create the textarea [...]
    
    // init ckeditor
    ckmodule.initEditor(myNewField, 'basic');

    // display field
    $('#mydiv').append(myNewField);
});

$(function() {
    $('#add-button').click(function (e) { 
        addNewField();
    });
});

